# A few questions about the graph of $y=x^3-4x+1$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, graphing-functions, tangent-line

a) Find an equation for the tangent line to the curve at the point (2,1).

b) What is the range of the values of the curve's slope?

c) Find equations for the tangent lines to the curve at the points where the slope of the tangent line is 8.

I know that asking questions on math.stackexchange that only want answers is not allowed. Therefore, can someone please walk me through some part of this question? Or at least help me start this question? Thank you! Any help is appreciated.

Update:
Okay, so I know that I need to find the derivative of this equation in order to get a slope. Using any of the linear equation equations, I plug in (2,1) and come up with the equation of the tangent line.

I do not know what extremal values nor do I know what is the domain of interest.

Finally, I do know what to do for the third hint, but I think I need to figure out b) first in order to do c).

Comment: 1) Do you know about the derivative? 2) Find extremal values of the derivative 3) solve equation of the derivative equals 8 and plug the solutions into the equation of the tangent. Apart from this, I like the argumentation: "please walk me through the question" *because* I cannot just ask for the answer :)

Comment: Oh my—thank you! You should make this into an actual answer, so I can up-vote it and then accept it! And nice username! :P

Comment: How in the world can I even include thoughts or attempts if I have no idea what to do? Jeez—you people have nothing better to do.

Comment: +1 For giving your own thoughts (although not in the original version, only in the edit).  But still I have to say that I find rather strange combination both asking both help and then saying in a comment: "Jeez—you people have nothing better to do."

Comment: @MartinSleziak, I apologize b/c I didn't clarify who my intended audience was. There was this specific person who marked my question as "Unclear," and as you can see above, I believe that my question is very clear.

Comment: From the [revision history](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1941596/revisions) I can see that your question was at one point closed as off-topic. I'd guess that the chosen reason was probably "missing context". As you can see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960), adding your own thoughts and attempts is not the only way to add context. (I will add link to [another related post on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/23169/can-we-stop-the-show-your-work-craze/23175#23175).)

Comment: Oh, oops, I think I must've read incorrectly.  ¯I_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $f(x)=x^3-4x+1$ and the derivative
$$f'(x)=3x^2-4.$$

As you said yourself in the question, you know that $f'(x)$ is the slope of the tangent line in the point $(x,f(x))$.

- Since $f'(2)=8$, you can see that the tangent line at the point $(2,1)$ is $$y=8x-15.$$
- You want the range of the values of $f'(x)=3x^2-4$. This is quadratic function - and you are probably already familiar with quadratics. You should be able to plot the graph or use $x^2\ge 0$ to see that $$f'(x)=3x^2-4 \ge -4$$
  so $f'(x)$ can only attain values from the interval $[-4,\infty)$. And from the properties of quadratic functions you should be able to see that all these values are also attained.
- If the slope is equal to $8$ then you have $$3x^2-4=8$$  which you can solve to get $x=\pm2$ and $f(x)=1$. So this gives you 
  $$y=8x+1\pm16,$$ i.e., $y=8x-15$ and $y=8x+17$. (The first one is precisely the same tangent line as in the first part.)

You can check at least some of the answers in WA:

- [tangent line of x^3-4x+1 at x=2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tangent+line+of+x%5E3-4x%2B1+at++x%3D2)
- [tangent line of x^3-4x+1 at x=-2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tangent+line+of+x%5E3-4x%2B1+at++x%3D-2)
- [plot x^3-4x+1, 8x-15, 8x+17](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%5E3-4x%2B1,+8x-15,+8x%2B17)

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1. Use the derivative.
2. Find extremal values of the derivative on the domain of interest.
3. Solve equation $f'(x)=8$ and plug the solutions into the equation of the tangent.